# How to change string at specific byte index nicely?

Tags: vimscript

I want to change 3rd byte of a string to `x`, i'm currently using this code:

```
let s = s[:1] . 'x' . s[3:]
```

It's a bit awkward, i wish i can do `let s[2] = 'x'`, but that's not allowed.

Are there any other built-in ways to do it nicely?

Answer (score 1):

In vimscript, strings are invariant: it would be very hard to
poke odd bytes into a series of Unicode characters without
trashing the entire thing.

Concatenation of parts as you have done is not so hard!

An alternative approach uses the substitute() function:

```
let s = substitute(s, "^\\(..\\).", "\\1x", "")
```

but that is not much more readable or flexible. It is possible to
wrap up both attacks in a more useable fashion:

```
function! s:replacechar(src, pos, chr)
  if len(a:src) < a:pos
    return a:src
  else
        return (a:pos ? a:src[0:(a:pos-1)] : "") . a:chr . a:src[(a:pos+1):]
  endif
endfunction

function! s:rereplacechar(src, pos, chr)
  let l:pat = "^\\(" . repeat(".", a:pos) . "\\).\\(.*\\)"
  let l:rep = "\\1" . a:chr . "\\2"
  return substitute(a:src, l:pat, l:rep, "")
endfunction
```

(Edit to correct a:p == 0 bug spotted by Mass)

Hope that helps

Tim

Comment: bug: when `a:pos = 0`, `a:pos-1` is `-1` and `a:src[0:-1]` yields the whole string.

Comment: @TimFerguson Thanks. But i only want to know other built-in ways to do this, function is not an option. No need to consider unicode, it's byte index, not character index. You code would be clearer if you use single quote string.